# New Year—New Tagline?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-line

### The Current Tag Line

We had several discussions over our site's tag line so far. It started out on day two of our private beta with the [initial ideas](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60) for our site's elevator pitch. We also had a few people discussing it in a [chat event](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49682/conversation/site-scope-event) focused on our site scope and getting the page off the ground when still in private beta. The resulting tag line was only a few inches of what has been there from the start in Area 51.

> Internet of Things Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for users of everyday objects embedded with electronics to be sensed, monitored, and controlled remotely. (Area 51; current tag line)

---

> Internet of Things Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for consumers and developers of interconnected objects embedded with electronics to be sensed, monitored, and controlled remotely. (Chat Event & highest voted in earliest discussion)

Those discussions took place back before we had any moderators. Even so, it's on us that we didn't get into contact with the CM team after we got appointed.

However, there has been some critique along the way regarding this tag line. The main points are that while giving a technically precise description of what the Internet of Things is it doesn't describe properly what kind of questions can be asked here. Half a year ago Aurora started a call for new ideas regarding the tag line and how to ["streamline the new user experience and make the site easier to discover and understand."](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290) As a result of that meta discussion Sean's suggestion for a help center text has been implemented and can be seen in the [help center overview](https://iot.stackexchange.com/help).

Especially enabling users to find out with a glance if their questions are on-topic in our little SE corner seems to be more difficult than we'd like. And while the refined suggestion from above is better it *doesn't address the most pressing issues.* People don't see if their question fits in.

- Is a Google Home/Alexa an *"interconnected object embedded with electronics to be sensed, monitored, and controlled remotely"*?
- I want to automate my home with IFTTT controlled lamps. On-topic?
- I want to build/develop a smart home solution. On-topic?

Sure, if one dives into the site all these questions are solid on-topic. The tagline however, doesn't give that easily away.

- **Home Automation**

  > As part of the focus group (new/potential users), this question seems really on point. I skipped past the site a few times because the name seemed too generic and not suggestive of the content. From the title alone the Home Improvement group seemed at least as appropriate for home automation.

  Source: [comment](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290/helping-this-site-grow-can-users-interested-in-our-site-find-us#comment452_290)
- **Google Home / Alexa**

  > When I search to find Google Home/Assistant answers on Stack Exchange sites I find them on the Internet of Things site. I believe that a regular (non-tech) user would have no idea why, and wouldn't think to look there.

  Source: [Area 51 answer](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27611)
- **Developer / Creators**

  This group is plainly not mentioned at all. It's also admittedly the only thing the above mentioned tag line refinement would address.

### A New Tag Line?!

- It should include the all groups of people we want to ask question on this site.
- It should make all feel people with an in-scope problem feel welcome.
- It should set certain boundaries on the scope of the site. What's in? What's out?
- It must not exceed 160 characters in the form "Q&A for ..." to not break the [SE site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list). However the 160 characters of *Artificial Intelligence* already look very bulky.

**Note: we'll be accepting suggestions until Friday 26 January. After that, we'll review any feedback and post the final proposals.** Please share your views below.

Answer (score 4):

I tried to include both the developers as well as the users while shortening the IoT description a bit and throwing in some areas of application.

> Q&A for builders and users of networked sensors and control devices in the contexts of smart homes, industry automation, or environmental sensors.

Comment: The part after the long dash relates to the control devices only, or also to the networked sensors? It isn't clear to me :)

Comment: @JNat From discussions with Helmar and others, I'm confident it's referring to both.

Comment: How do you feel about "...and control devices in the contexts of smart homes, industry automation, or environmental sensors." instead? It might be a minor thing, but the long dash formatting seems a bit off to me. And I believe I'm reading your proposed copy right in my proposed one, @anonymous2?

Comment: Yes, and I personally would definitely be great with your proposed wording, though I'm not sure if it sounds a bit like if your question is outside the scope of "smart homes, industry automation, or environmental sensors," your question is off-topic.

Comment: I see your point, @anonymous2, but re-reading the proposed copy from Helmar, I think your concerns would still apply there. We could always end it with an "and others" though that might suddenly make the whole thing too broad. Are there any specific contexts that would be important to not be left out, or... I don't know; thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

While not my personal favorite anymore, I won't tuck this away. The suggestion from last year.

> Internet of Things Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for consumers and developers of interconnected objects embedded with electronics to be sensed, monitored, and controlled remotely.